# NANT process time out after 1800 sec

Tags: nant, deployment, cctray

I am using NANT to deploy the code to servers using s/w CCtray.
sometimes I get this error but looks like the vsts is up according to the administrator.
He can't figure out why it is saying this error and neither do I.
Because it doesn't log any other information other than this.
DOes anyone has faced this kind of error before and if yes how did you solve it?
Or what are the options by which you could get this error.

alice triggered a build (ForceBuild)

Comment: do you get a stacktrace? if so, please post it.

Comment: NO actually I don't get any stack trace when this fails.That's what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I've have this, particularly when building large projects in NAnt build scripts under the CruiseControl .net continuous integration server.

The fix for this is quite easy, in that you need to override the default CruiseControl timeout (1800 seconds) by doing something like this inside your C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ccnet.config file:

```
<tasks>
    <nant>
        <baseDirectory>c:\your-folder\your-system</baseDirectory>
        <buildFile>your-system.build</buildFile>
        <buildTimeoutSeconds>2400</buildTimeoutSeconds>
    </nant>
</tasks>
```

This then buys your process more time, but still give CruiseControl a fighting chance of killing a process if it goes on for too long (abnormally).

Any good?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you're deploying with CCNet, since CCTray is just the windows-based monitor for CCNet.

You should have your build script spit out debugging statements at various intervals so you can tell exactly what part of the build is failing.

What happens when you run it manually on your machine or the build server?

Comment: THere are debugging statements in my build scripts. It tells me it is rendering that means doing something on reports page but finally when it finsihes it just says the NANT process timed out.

Comment: You'll need to isolate and post the section of the build script that's timing out in order for us to answer your question.

Comment: Actually I don't know which part of the build script is timing out.It is just telling me that time out exception.And there is no logging for any of the targets it hits in the build scripts. MY assumption is that when it tries to deploy the code due to slow n/w when it fails in the middle it just gives you exception without logging anything.

Comment: Ok, then what you'll need to do is cut out the entire build script and add it back piece-by-piece until you find the section that's causing the problem.  "My build script times out" isn't something someone can help you fix - you'll need to do some more digging until you get to a more specific issue.